# kuberenetes pod is running but not accessible from web

Tags: kubernetes

I have created nginx deployment and service file. i am trying to access the running pod from web browser.
all traffic is allowed on my instance. however, when i am trying access it via public dns, i am not able to reach

nginx.yaml:

```
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-nginx
        image: nginx: latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP

"nginx.yaml" 34L
```

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
my-nginx-6d5dd88d4c-2lh74   1/1     Running   0          26s
```

```
kubectl get svc my-nginx
NAME       TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
my-nginx   NodePort   10.107.36.102   <none>        8080:31238/TCP   75s
```

Comment: how are you trying to access and from where? same server, over the internet, vpn, some other unknown way?

Comment: there are a lot of details missing but considering "all traffic is allowed on my instance"

You should use the public IPof your instance with port number 31238 as its a node port set up. ( in case you are trying on 8080 or something else ).